# Light Fixture - power but no light

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, troubleshooting

Yesterday I installed a new light over our dining table. At first everything seemed to work fine, but last night I turned on the light and it sparked and the light went out. I turned off the power and left trouble shooting for this morning.

Here's what I've discovered this morning -

-The breaker wasn't thrown and appears visually fine. 
-The black wire may have grounded against the mounting plate - it looks like there is a small cut in the wire insulation. This probably occurred when I was shoving the wires back inside.
-After wrapping the wire in electrical tape and hooking up the light again, it's still not working - no light. 
-When testing the wires coming from the ceiling (using multimeter), there is 120V between power and ground and 120V between power and neutral. 
I checked the light fixture by connecting the wires to an extension cord and it works (so the light fixture or bulbs aren't the problem). 
-The light switch looks fine as do all the connections. 
-Using an extension cord, I tried to hook-up a desk lamp the ceiling wires and also got no light. 
-As far as I can tell, this light/switch is the only outlet on the breaker.

I'm stumped. Any suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Thanks,

-Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. Apparently the dimmer switch ended up being the culprit. It must have shorted out when the wire sparked last night.